# Can I enumerate the instance methods of a Java interface in JRuby?

Tags: ruby, jruby, introspection

I'm trying to enumerate the methods of an interface from the Ruby side, which as far as I know, JRuby maps to modules.

What I thought should work:

```
name = # omitting logic which is currently iterating entries of a jar file
clazz = name.constantize
clazz.instance_methods
```

If I call `instance_methods` on some real module like `Enumerable`, I get a full list of all the methods I see documented.

Likewise, if I call `instance_methods` on some Java interface like `Comparable` or `Collection` which is treated specially by JRuby, I do get a list, but it only includes the special Ruby methods, not all the methods present on the interface.

Calling it on any other interface returns `[]`, which isn't particularly useful.

I know I can drop to `java_class` and use Java introspection to get the declared methods, but I specifically want the Ruby names for all the methods because I'm trying to compare the contents of the jar with the results of running the specs, to try and find untested methods.

Is there a proper way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

try `java_instance_methods` on the `java_class` of the interface e.g. :

```
>> Java::JavaLang::CharSequence.java_class.java_instance_methods.map(&:name)
=> ["toString", "charAt", "length", "subSequence"]
```